# Installed Fedora But Can't Boot To It

Tags: linux, windows, boot, fedora

I installed Fedora on my laptop but can't seem to figure out how to select it to boot. I created a 20 Gig partition on my HDD for it and it said it installed sucessfully. However, now whenever I reboot, it just boots to Windows 10. I checked the advanced system settings but only Windows 10 is listed. Additionally, I checked the BIOS but didn't see any options. I tried some of the function keys but nothing seems to work. There has to be an option though to change the boot operating system. Does anyone have any ideas? It's an Asus X502C.